# Is there any package that lets you document your gruntfile, similar to apiDocs for Node?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, documentation

I have a great project set up, with tons of grunt tasks in it. The problem is, it's bloated. The `gruntfile.js` alone has 1200+ lines. I want to be able to document all these grunt plugins I've installed, through annotations in code like [apiDocs](http://apidocjs.com/) does. Are there any packages out there that does this? Or, is there a a dfferent way to document your grunt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Gruntfile is 1200 lines long, I strongly suggest you to [split it into multiple files](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/supercharging-your-gruntfile/).

You gruntfile is simply a NodeJs app, which means that it's written in JS and the most popular documentator for JS is [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org).

So a task could look like :

**grunt/uglify.js**

```
/**
 * Minify javascript files
 *
 * @description
 * Here is a detailed explanation of what this uglify task can do
 * 
 * @type {Object}
 */
module.exports = {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dist/build.min.js': ['dist/build.js']
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: That's great. But is there a grunt plugin that picks up these annotations and neatly puts it in a web page like apidocs or ngdocs does?

Comment: As any documentator, JSDoc does generate an HTML documentation : http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html#generating-a-website. If you want to use Grunt to do that, you can use [grunt-jsdoc](https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc).